# Cartogram in R not distorting countries as expected

Tags: r, cartogram

I'm using the `cartogram` package in R to make a world map of living languages. The country map is from [Natural Earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/cultural/ne_110m_admin_0_map_units.zip), and the language count from the [Ethnologue](https://www.ethnologue.com/).

```
w <- readOGR('.','ne_110m_admin_0_map_units')
L <- read.csv('languages.csv',sep='\t')
w$rank <- 1:nrow(w)
wl <- merge(w@data,L,by.x='ISO_A3',by.y='iso3',all.x=T)
wl <- wl[order(wl$rank),]
wl[is.na(wl$Live),'Live'] <- 1
w@data <- wl
w2 <- cartogram_cont(w,'Live',prepare='none')
plot(w2)
```

[image: Living languages cartogram]

The data I'm using has 111 living languages in Russia and 299 in China, almost the triple. However, the cartogram created still displays Russia larger than China.

Here is the data from each country:

```
> w@data[order(w$NAME),c('NAME','Live')]
                        NAME Live
13               Afghanistan   41
15                   Albania    8
57                   Algeria   18
14                    Angola   45
19                Antarctica    1
17                 Argentina   24
18                   Armenia    8
21                 Australia  206
22                   Austria   14
23                Azerbaijan   18
30                   Bahamas    3
28                Bangladesh   41
32                   Belarus    4
25                   Belgium   11
33                    Belize    8
26                     Benin   55
37                    Bhutan   23
34                   Bolivia   43
31          Bosnia and Herz.    4
38                  Botswana   31
12              Bougainville    1
35                    Brazil  218
36                    Brunei   15
29                  Bulgaria   12
27              Burkina Faso   71
24                   Burundi    3
99                  Cambodia   27
45                  Cameroon  277
40                    Canada   96
39      Central African Rep.   72
161                     Chad  131
42                     Chile   11
43                     China  299
48                  Colombia   84
47                     Congo   62
49                Costa Rica   11
44             Côte d'Ivoire   85
82                   Croatia   15
50                      Cuba    3
51                    Cyprus    4
52                   Czechia   10
46           Dem. Rep. Congo  211
55                   Denmark    5
54                  Djibouti    5
56            Dominican Rep.    4
58                   Ecuador   24
59                     Egypt   15
152              El Salvador    5
2                    England    1
75                Eq. Guinea   14
60                   Eritrea   15
63                   Estonia    7
159                 eSwatini    5
64                  Ethiopia   88
67              Falkland Is.    1
66                      Fiji   10
65                   Finland   13
20    Fr. S. Antarctic Lands    1
68                    France   22
79             French Guiana   13
69                     Gabon   43
73                    Gambia   11
70                   Georgia   20
53                   Germany   25
71                     Ghana   81
76                    Greece   18
77                 Greenland    3
78                 Guatemala   27
72                    Guinea   36
74             Guinea-Bissau   23
80                    Guyana   16
83                     Haiti    4
81                  Honduras   10
84                   Hungary   17
90                   Iceland    2
86                     India  448
85                 Indonesia  707
88                      Iran   78
89                      Iraq   23
87                   Ireland    5
91                    Israel   34
92                     Italy   34
93                   Jamaica    4
95                     Japan   15
94                    Jordan   11
96                Kazakhstan   14
97                     Kenya   67
5                     Kosovo    1
101                   Kuwait    3
98                Kyrgyzstan    6
102                     Laos   83
110                   Latvia    7
103                  Lebanon    7
107                  Lesotho    5
104                  Liberia   31
105                    Libya    9
108                Lithuania   10
109               Luxembourg    4
115                Macedonia   10
113               Madagascar   14
122                   Malawi   17
123                 Malaysia  134
116                     Mali   68
121               Mauritania    7
114                   Mexico  287
112                  Moldova   10
119                 Mongolia   12
118               Montenegro    6
111                  Morocco   14
120               Mozambique   43
117                  Myanmar  118
4                  N. Cyprus    1
1                 N. Ireland    1
124                  Namibia   27
130                    Nepal  121
129              Netherlands   15
125            New Caledonia   38
131              New Zealand    4
128                Nicaragua   11
126                    Niger   23
127                  Nigeria  519
139              North Korea    1
6                     Norway    1
132                     Oman   17
133                 Pakistan   74
134                   Panama   15
7           Papua New Guinea    1
141                 Paraguay   23
135                     Peru   93
136              Philippines  183
137                   Poland   21
140                 Portugal    9
138              Puerto Rico    4
142                    Qatar    3
143                  Romania   23
144                   Russia  111
145                   Rwanda    3
154                 S. Sudan   69
146             Saudi Arabia    7
8                   Scotland    1
148                  Senegal   38
3                     Serbia    1
151             Sierra Leone   24
156                 Slovakia   11
157                 Slovenia    7
150              Solomon Is.   73
153                  Somalia   13
9                 Somaliland    1
181             South Africa   30
100              South Korea    3
62                     Spain   16
106                Sri Lanka    7
147                    Sudan   75
155                 Suriname   21
149             Svalbard Is.    1
158                   Sweden   15
41               Switzerland   12
160                    Syria   18
170                   Taiwan   22
164               Tajikistan   13
171                 Tanzania  125
163                 Thailand   71
166              Timor-Leste   20
162                     Togo   44
167      Trinidad and Tobago    7
168                  Tunisia    6
169                   Turkey   39
165             Turkmenistan    6
172                   Uganda   43
173                  Ukraine   22
16      United Arab Emirates   10
175 United States of America  219
174                  Uruguay    5
176               Uzbekistan   11
179                  Vanuatu  111
177                Venezuela   42
178                  Vietnam  109
61                 W. Sahara    3
10                     Wales    1
11                 West Bank    1
180                    Yemen   11
182                   Zambia   46
183                 Zimbabwe   22
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT

Following FuzzyLeapfrog's answer, I removed Antarctica and transformed the map to Robinson projection.

```
w <- w[-grep('Antarctica',w$NAME),]
w1 <- spTransform(w,CRS('+proj=robin'))
w2 <- cartogram_cont(w1,'Live')
tom <- 1 - w$Live/max(w$Live) # tonality
plot(w,col=rgb(tom,tom,tom))
plot(w1,col=rgb(tom,tom,tom))
plot(w2,col=rgb(tom,tom,tom))
```

Following are the three maps: in Mercator projection, in Robinson projection, and after the deformation. The gray tone is proportional to the number of living languages (the darker, the greater the number).

[image: Mercator projection]

[image: Robinson projection]

[image: Robinson projection, deformed]

Don't you think that still Russia is bigger than China, when it should be about 1/3 of it?

EDIT2

The Natural Earth map above is a lightweight shapefile (the .shp has only 182 kB). Using a more detailed map (.shp with 6.5 MB), I've got the following maps (Robinson projection and Robinson deformed). Russia's still too big! I wonder if the country's original size influences the final shape (I thought it didn't, but now I'm thinking it does). There might be an option so that the original size doesn't affect the final result?

[image: detailed Robinson projection]

[image: detailed Robinson deformed]

EDIT3

I tried two equal area projections, Mollweide and Lambert Cylindrical. Below are the results for Lambert's, now in red, first the projected map, then the projected+deformed map. The more red, the greater the area should be. But it's not the case (just compare Papua New Guinea with Australia).

[image: Lambert Equal Area Projection]

[image: Lambert Equal Area Projection + cartogram deformation]

I wonder if `cartogram_cont` function from `cartogram` package really does what I think it should be doing; the help page says it follows the "rubber sheet distortion algorithm (Dougenik et al. 1985)".

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. We need something we can copy/paste into R to run.

Comment: @MrFlick Yes, I wanted to do that, though I'm not sure how to put those values in a text format that you can simply copy and paste into R. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Not only russia and china are not sized properly but Antarctica, too. Looks like you are using a Mercator projection. I'd suggest to transorm the world map data and exclude Antarctica, e.g. like suggested in [this blog post](https://nowosad.github.io/post/world-pop-change/):

```
library(dplyr) # data manipulation
[...]
world_map = ne_countries(returnclass = "sf")
world_map = world_map %>% 
    select(sovereignt) %>% 
    filter(sovereignt != "Antarctica") %>% 
    st_transform(world_map, crs = "+proj=robin")
[...]
```

What deforms the size of the contries is a) the projection and b) the weight (in your case the amout of languages) you add. The impact of a) becomes smaller, e.g. by narrowing down the region you look at or by using an equal-area projection, like Mollweide.

Comment: I've edited the question to show what your answer gave me.

Comment: @Rodrigo What deforms the size/shape of the contries is a) the projection and b) the weight (languages) you add. The impact of a) becomes smaller, e.g. by narrowing down the region you look at. Maybe this is an option.

Comment: I didn't get what you meant by "narrowing down the region you look at". I need a world map. I've added new maps with a more detailed shapefile, please take a look.

Comment: @Rodrigo I meant that you could only look at a map section and not the whole globe.

Comment: Ok, but that's not an option here.

Comment: @Rodrigo Okay, then you should try to use an equal-area projection.

Comment: @Rodrigo Maybe Mollweide. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Both Mollweide and Lambert's Equal Area still don't give the expected results. I updated my question in EDIT3. Please take a look.

Comment: @Rodrigo The new example doesn't look like an equal-area projection, e.g. it is a rectangular map. I'd highly recomment to dive deeper into the projections topic or to learn more about the underlying algorithm.

Comment: It's Lambert cylindrical equal-area projection, `spTransform(w,CRS('+proj=cea'))`.